# Creating a Query Activity in Java

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, query, triggered-send, tracking

I am new to SalesForce and I am trying to create a query activity that is explained in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/creating_a_query_activity.html to retrieve the events (sent, open and click) happened on our triggered send emails. I cannot create my own API call because there is not any sample in java.
I appreciate any help. I got the sample in java but I cannot get the required object from fuel sdk. please don't close my question, I am waiting for my comment on the answer to be replied.

Roya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can create a Query Activity in Salesforce Marketing Cloud using the Marketing Cloud SDK and Java:

```
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient;
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETDataExtension;
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETDataExtensionColumn;
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETDataExtensionRow;
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETDataExtensionRowResult;
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETResponse;
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETResult;
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETQueryActivity;

public class QueryActivityExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ETSdkException {
        // Initialize the Marketing Cloud SDK
        ETClient client = new ETClient();

        // Create a new Query Activity
        ETQueryActivity queryActivity = new ETQueryActivity();
        queryActivity.setName("My Query Activity");
        queryActivity.setDescription("This is a Query Activity to retrieve tracking data from Data Views.");

        // Set the Data Extension to be used by the Query Activity
        ETDataExtension dataExtension = new ETDataExtension();
        dataExtension.setName("Tracking Data");
        queryActivity.setDataExtension(dataExtension);

        // Set the query for the Query Activity
        String query = "SELECT * FROM TrackingData";
        queryActivity.setQuery(query);

        // Save the Query Activity to Marketing Cloud
        ETResponse<ETQueryActivity> response = client.create(queryActivity);
        if (response.getStatus() == ETResult.Status.OK) {
            ETQueryActivity createdQueryActivity = response.getObject();
            System.out.println("Query Activity created with ID: " + createdQueryActivity.getId());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error creating Query Activity: " + response.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This code creates a new Query Activity with the name "My Query Activity" and the description "This is a Query Activity to retrieve tracking data from Data Views." It sets the Data Extension to be used by the Query Activity to be a Data Extension named "Tracking Data", and sets the query for the Query Activity to be "SELECT * FROM TrackingData". Finally, it saves the Query Activity to Marketing Cloud and prints the ID of the created Query Activity if the operation is successful, or an error message if there was an issue.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Thank you so much, it is very helpful! The only issue is that I cannot  find ETQueryActivity and ETDataExtensionRowResult in the sdk. I am checking it from here, is it the right place: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java?search=1

Comment: I want to use " com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETQueryActivity"
 to create query activity how can I get this object? or what do you recommend me to create a query activity's objects?

Comment: Thank you so much, it is very helpful! The only issue is that I cannot find ETQueryActivity and ETDataExtensionRowResult in the sdk. I am checking it from here, is it the right place: github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java?search=1 –