# Need java objects for a Query Activity to retrieve tracking data from Data Views

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, triggered-send

I've got an example of how I can create a Query Activity in Salesforce Marketing Cloud using the Marketing Cloud SDK and Java from @zuzannamj:

```java
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient;
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETDataExtension;
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETDataExtensionColumn;
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETDataExtensionRow;
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETDataExtensionRowResult;
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETResponse;
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETResult;
import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETQueryActivity;

public class QueryActivityExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ETSdkException {
        // Initialize the Marketing Cloud SDK
        ETClient client = new ETClient();

        // Create a new Query Activity
        ETQueryActivity queryActivity = new ETQueryActivity();
        queryActivity.setName("My Query Activity");
        queryActivity.setDescription("This is a Query Activity to retrieve tracking data from Data Views.");

        // Set the Data Extension to be used by the Query Activity
        ETDataExtension dataExtension = new ETDataExtension();
        dataExtension.setName("Tracking Data");
        queryActivity.setDataExtension(dataExtension);

        // Set the query for the Query Activity
        String query = "SELECT * FROM TrackingData";
        queryActivity.setQuery(query);

        // Save the Query Activity to Marketing Cloud
        ETResponse<ETQueryActivity> response = client.create(queryActivity);
        if (response.getStatus() == ETResult.Status.OK) {
            ETQueryActivity createdQueryActivity = response.getObject();
            System.out.println("Query Activity created with ID: " + createdQueryActivity.getId());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error creating Query Activity: " + response.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that I cannot find ETQueryActivity and ETDataExtensionRowResult in the sdk. I am checking it from here, is it the right place: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java?search=1

I want to use `com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETQueryActivity` to create query activity how can I get this object? or how do you recommend me to create a query activity's objects?

Comment: Directly @mentioning users when they aren't in the question does nothing. Furthermore, it is rude.

Comment: Hi @DerekF  He suggested me this solution in another post and I commented there to ask him but I don't know why my case got closed (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/392850/creating-a-query-activity-in-java) and I have no other way to ask him.  Can you please suggest me what to do? He was the only one who gave me the answer I needed. I am new to this community and I appreciate any help.

Comment: I was trying to get his attention, I don't know why in this community my post and comments gets deleted by people without asking me! Isn't it supposed to be a safe place to teach and learn from each other?! Why every one is so harsh!!